# Typescript: union type convers to never in conditional type

Tags: typescript

I found an issue which I don't know how to overcome...

I created a simple type to demonstrate the problem:

```
type SimpleTest<U> = U extends {something: string}
    ? () => void
    : (a: U) => U
```

And this type does not work as I wanted with union types:

```
function test(a: SimpleTest<'test' | 'rest'>) {
    a('test');     // Error: TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
}
```

There is an error because TypeScript interprets type `SimpleTest<'test' | 'rest'>` as `(a: never) => ("test" | "rest")`.
But I want it to be `(a: "test" | "rest") => ("test" | "rest")`.

What is really surprising for me that the type of the returning value is correct, but the same type in the function parameter is transformed to `never`...

I tried some things to find a workaround but without any success...

Comment: Your `SimpleTest<U>` is a [*distributive* conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) so `SimpleTest<'test' | 'rest'>` is equivalent to `SimpleTest<'test'> | SimpleTest<'rest'>` and is therefore a union of function types.  A union of functions can only be safely called with an intersection of their parameters, and `'test' & 'rest'` is `never` because there is no value which is both those strings.

Comment: ...If you don't want a distributive conditional type, you can prevent the union distribution like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3PQqW).  Does that fully address your question? If so I can write up an answer.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Wow, that works just like a magic! Thank you very much, it's exactly what I've needed. Please write your comment as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Will do, it might be an hour or two before I get to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SimpleTest<U>` is (accidentally) a [*distributive* conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) because it is of the form `XXX extends YYY ? AAA : BBB` where `XXX` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  Distributive conditional types *distribute* over [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in their inputs.  So if `F<T>` is a distributive conditional types, then `F<A | B | C>` is equivalent to `F<A> | F<B> | F<C>`: the union input is split into its individual members, the type function is applied to each member, and the result is joined back together in a union.

And so `SimpleTest<'test' | 'rest'>` is evaluated as `SimpleTest<'test'> | SimpleTest<'rest'>`:

```
type Test = SimpleTest<'test' | 'rest'>;
// type Test = ((a: "test") => "test") | ((a: "rest") => "rest")
```

This is a [union of function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types), and unions of function types aren't generally easy to call.  If I handed you a function and said it's either a function that accepts only `"test"` or it's a function that accepts only `"rest"` but I don't know which one, then you couldn't call it safely with either `"test"` or `"rest"`.  That's a general feature of a union of functions; you can only safely pass it an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the parameter types... if you had a value which was both `"rest"` *and* `"test"`, then you could call the function.  But there are no values like that; the intersection `"rest" & "test"` is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), and that's why you get the error:

```
a('test'); // error! 'string' is not assignable to 'never'.
```

---

When you have a conditional type that's unintentionally distributive, you can make it non-distributive by modifying it so that the checked type is not a generic type parameter itself.  The tersest way to do this is to change `XXX extends YYY ? AAA : BBB` to `[XXX] extends [YYY] ? AAA : BBB`.  Technically you're now comparing two single-element [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), which are considered [covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) in their elements, so `[XXX] extends [YYY]` if and only if `XXX extends YYY`.  But since `[XXX]` isn't a generic type parameter (it's a tuple containing such a type parameter), the conditional type is no longer distributive.

So you can make this change:

```
type SimpleTest<U> = [U] extends [{ something: string }]
  ? () => void
  : (a: U) => U
```

And now things behave as expected, and `SimpleTest<U>` is never a union of functions, no matter what you plug in for `U`:

```
type Test = SimpleTest<'test' | 'rest'>;
// type Test = (a: "test" | "rest") => "test" | "rest"

function test(a: SimpleTest<'test' | 'rest'>) {
  a('test');  // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Thank you, you are real TypeScript expert!